# Is there a mathematical way to deduce that my directed graph is disconnected?

Tags: graphs

I have a graph G with 13814 nodes and 25190 edges. I am interested in finding a mathematical proposition that proves that my graph is disconnected. I know it is, because the visualization shows lonely clusters where they have no way of reaching the other nodes in the graph. This simply is a signature of disconnected graphs. But, is there a mathematical way to prove whether my graph is disconnected?

Comment: Are you interested in a mathematical proof or in an efficient algorithm (there are some very efficient ones)? In any case, you should explain how your graph is given.

Comment: It depends on the graph. There are many "mathematical propositions" for proving connectedness or disconnectedness. Which one you apply depends on the problem you're trying to solve. If you don't explain us your problem, we can't help you.

Comment: You really should tell what you want to do with your "mathematical way". Why isn't looking at the picture good enough? Do you intend to prove a theorem, or implement a program for checking connectivity, or what?

Comment: I thought my question was self explanatory.

Comment: Voting to close. Question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose any random node and touch any all the nodes linked to that node and all the children (BFS, DFS or any algorithm like minimum spanning tree). After that, you can check if there are untouched nodes, and if there are, then it implies that your graph is disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

If the multiplicity of zero as an eigenvalue of the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Properties) of your graph is greater than one, your graph is disconnected.

Comment: Formula if there is any?

Comment: That *is* the "formula".

Comment: No it isnt, its just text. I am not joking here.

Comment: This answer appears to be deliberately obtuse. If the person who is asking the question knew what an eigenvalue or a Laplacian was, I'm pretty sure they'd know how to tell if a graph is connected.

Comment: @AliGajani: this answer contains a link to the definition of the Laplacian of a graph, and the statement that graph is disconnected if and only if the Laplacian has zero eigenvalue of multiplicity greater than one (in fact, the multiplicity of $\lambda_0$ equals to the number of connected components of the graph). It's not too difficult to compute the multiplicity of $\lambda_0$ in a number of ways, ranging from you favourite matrix decompositions to observing last coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, whichever you prefer. So yes, there is a formula in this answer.

Comment: That's what I wanted, a complete answer. I would love if someone can show it to me, hence the question was asked. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't come and ask. Thank you for your detailed insight into this Michael.

Comment: @AliGajani There are many ways of determining if a graph is connected. Learning about Laplacians and calculating eigenvalues is possibly the most complicated way of doing it. Depth-first search, Dijkstra's algorithm, Prim's algorithm, Floyd-Warshall will all deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

There is one way to derive disconnectivity from number of nodes $n$ and edges $m$ alone: if $m < n-1$, the graph is disconnected.

That is not the case for your graph. There may be other parameters/properties that allow the conclusions, but it's unlikely you can compute these faster than the naive approach (if you don't have them given in your setting):

Perform a graph traversal starting in any node. If it does not visit all nodes, your graph is disconnected.

Comment: Right so DFS that is.